# Angular unit testing Controller with service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test using karma and jasmine for an Angular controller that depends on a service

storesController.js

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('storesController', ['storesService']);

app.controller('StoresListController', function ($scope, StoresService) {


    $scope.getStores = function () {
        StoresService.getStores().then(function (data) {
            $scope.stores = data.data;
        });
    };
    $scope.getStores();

    $scope.deleteStore = function (id) {
        StoresService.deleteStore(id).then(function () {
            $scope.getStores();
        });

    };
});
```

storesService.js

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('storesService', []);

app.factory('StoresService', ['$http', function ($http) {

        var stores = [];

        stores.getStores = function () {
           return $http.get(/api/getStores');
        };            
        stores.deleteStore = function (storeID) {
            return $http.delete(/api/deleteStore/'+storeID);
        };
        return stores;

    }]);
})();
```

And the test,
controllers.spec.js

```
describe('StoresController', function () {
    beforeEach(module('storesController'));

    var scope;
    var storesServiceMock;
    var controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {

        storesServiceMock = {
            getStores: function() {
            },
            deleteStores: function() {
            }
       };
       spyOn(storesServiceMock, 'getStores').and.returnValue({name : 'TestName', country : 'TestCountry'}) 

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('StoresListController', {
           $scope: scope, StoresService: storesServiceMock
       });
    }));

    it('scope.stores should be defined', function () {
          expect(scope.stores).toBeDefined;
    });
});
```

And I'm getting

```
TypeError: StoresService.getStores(...).then is not a function at n.$scope.getStores
```

I've also tried width httpBackend but I'm not be able to make it work, any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the spy return a promise.

With ES2015:

```
spyOn(storesServiceMock, 'getStores').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({name : 'TestName', country : 'TestCountry'}));
```

With $q:

```
spyOn(storesServiceMock, 'getStores').and.callFake(function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({name : 'TestName', country : 'TestCountry'}));
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Comment: it works on chrome and firefox but throws and error on ie, ReferenceError: 'Promise' is not defined at Anonymous function

Comment: Sorry, you'll need a newer browser or use something like Babel to transpile (or create a promise using angulars $q library).

Comment: well, something is still going wrong with my test. It passes with `expect(scope.stores).toBeDefined(); `and `expect(scope.stores).toBeUnDefined(); `,that shouldn't happen and still not working `expect(scope.stores.lenth).toBeLessThan(2)`, got can not get the 'length' property of null or undefined

Comment: You have to call `$scope.$digest()` before asserting your store is populated, promises are asynchronous.